# Changing testing environments for DEBUG. C#. NUnit

Tags: c#, testing, automation, nunit, test-environments

There is a problem of switching test environments when developing autotests and debugging them.

When starting remotely, there are mandatory parameters for selecting the testing environment, there are no problems here.

The code looks like this:

```
public static string testEnvironment = Keys.GetTestEnvironment(EnvironmentTesting.Regress);
```

And I use it as a selector to select the testing environment.

But this is inconvenient and therefore I would like to choose a more practical solution, I will be glad of any advice on the topic.

As a stub, I implemented what I have now, a variable selection selector.

I tried to implement via variables inside the project via Debug/Application arguments, but I doubt that this will be the solution to this problem.

Comment: have you tried to use `#IF DEBUG` and the  set the ENV based on that compiler condition?

Comment: No, not do it. Use argument command line in Debug properties